# HTML this.id does not function as expected

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to learn HTML and have run into a problem that shows I must fundamentally misunderstand something about how this keyword works.

I am using a select to display a relevant image (when one of two options is selected the image should show). The code I have looks like this:

```
    <select onchange="document.getElementById('preview').src =     document.getElementById(this.id).getAttribute('data-value')">
           <option id = "id1"  data-value="Image1"> Image1 </option>
        <option id = "id2"  data-value="Image2"> Image2 </option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <img id="preview" height="200px">
```

Running this code the image does not display and I get no errormessage. If I replace this.id by 'id1' (ie manually specify the id) the image display as expected but then the image cannot be changed by selecting option.

I could replace document.getElementById(this.id).getAttribute('data-value') -> this.value, but I have reserved the value attribute for another feature.

Is there another way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your code a bit. using the actual options in place of the `this`

```
 <select onchange="document.getElementById('preview').src = document.getElementById('preview').options[document.getElementById('preview').selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-value')">
           <option id = "id1"  data-value="Image1"> Image1 </option>
        <option id = "id2"  data-value="Image2"> Image2 </option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <img id="preview" height="200px">
```

It will likely be better to define this `onChange` as a function outside the markup.

Answer (score 0):

In the event handler, `this` is the element itself, the `<select>`. Also, the `change` event just doesn't tell what you want. You could simply write a `console.log(event)` there and check what attributes it has. Or look up in the documentation of course, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement#events links both `change` and `input` (it doesn't tell the new value either).
What you can do instead is using `this`, and the `selectedOptions` "array":

```html
<select onchange="document.getElementById('preview').innerText = this.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute('data-value')">
  <option id="id1" data-value="Image1"> Image1 </option>
  <option id="id2" data-value="Image2"> Image2 </option>
</select>
<br>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should learn to code clean and that you do by using the right techniques.

First you should not use the `onclick` attribute in 2023 anymore but use an `addEventListener` and split JS and HTML completely apart.
You don't need to select an option within the select. The right approach is to give the option a `value` instead of a `data` attribute. BY that the select value si always the value of the selected option:

```js
const SELECT = document.querySelector('select');
const IMG = document.querySelector('#preview');

SELECT.addEventListener('change', function() {
  let value = SELECT.value;
  console.log(value);
  IMG.src= `https://via.placeholder.com/100.jpg/${value}`;
});
```

```css
img
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="FF0000"> Image1 </option>
  <option value="0000FF"> Image2 </option>
</select>
<br>
<img id="preview" height="200px" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.jpg/FF0000">
```